# Why Rails replace the nested form fills with nils when inserting in database, but insert "created_at" and "updated_at"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, haml

I have a Ruby on Rails app that contain two controllers (categories and documentations). The documentations controller is a nested controller (from categories, of course).

In the documentations controllers, I have a form to add data in my database. When I use this form, Rails add *nil* values in database, instead of the content of the form.

I use the default Rails database (sqlite3)

I use two gems in this parts of the code: *friendly_id* and *haml*.

This is the log:

```
Started GET "/categories/ruby_on_rails" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-20 14:18:47 -0400
Processing by CategoriesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"ruby_on_rails"}
  Category Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."slug" = ? LIMIT ?  [["slug", "ruby_on_rails"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering categories/show.html.haml within layouts/application
  Rendered documentations/_form.html.haml (2.5ms)
  Documentation Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "documentations".* FROM "documentations" WHERE "documentations"."category_id" = ?  [["category_id", 2]]
  Rendered categories/show.html.haml within layouts/application (5.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 18ms (Views: 16.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)


Started POST "/categories/ruby_on_rails/documentations" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-20 14:24:06 -0400
Processing by DocumentationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"zY+HjYiKv98/2BvWwn7ZFqzzdS3JfoFIV8aNnOc1t9LV+SYC9F2xqV+O5UgZI49+aJkuGf3zAeVIUAOa8BQa5w==", "documentation"=>{"titre"=>"test", "contenu"=>"test"}, "commit"=>"Créer la documentation", "category_id"=>"ruby_on_rails"}
  Category Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."slug" = ? LIMIT ?  [["slug", "ruby_on_rails"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "documentations" ("category_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["category_id", 2], ["created_at", "2018-03-20 18:24:06.217357"], ["updated_at", "2018-03-20 18:24:06.217357"]]
   (9.9ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://127.0.0.1:3000/categories/ruby_on_rails
Completed 302 Found in 28ms (ActiveRecord: 11.5ms)


Started GET "/categories/ruby_on_rails" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-20 14:24:06 -0400
Processing by CategoriesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"ruby_on_rails"}
  Category Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."slug" = ? LIMIT ?  [["slug", "ruby_on_rails"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering categories/show.html.haml within layouts/application
  Rendered documentations/_form.html.haml (2.8ms)
  Documentation Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "documentations".* FROM "documentations" WHERE "documentations"."category_id" = ?  [["category_id", 2]]
  Rendered categories/show.html.haml within layouts/application (6.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 24ms (Views: 22.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

```
class DocumentationsController < ApplicationController  
    def create
        #@category = Category.friendly.find(params[:id])
        #@documentation = @category.documentation.create(documentation_params)
        @category = Category.friendly.find(params[:category_id])
        @documentation = @category.documentations.create(params[:documentations_params])
        redirect_to category_path(@category)
    end

    def show
        @category = Category.friendly.find(params[:category_id])
        #@documentation = @category.documentations.friendly.find(params[:id])
    end

    private
        def documentation_params
            #params.require(:category[:category_id], :documentation).permit(:titre, :contenu, :slug, :proprietaire)
            params.require(:documentation).permit(:titre, :contenu, :slug, :proprietaire)
        end
end
```

This is my form (_form.html.haml)

```
= form_with(model: [ @category, @category.documentations.build ], local: true) do |f|

    %label= :titre
    %br
    = f.text_field :titre
    %br
    %br
    = f.label :contenu
    %br
    = f.text_area :contenu
    %br
    %br
    = f.submit 'Créer la documentation'
```

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Finally, I just rewrite all the code, and now it works, so question solved!